# Was one of the victims in the recent Israeli hospital raid in a coma?

Tags: israel, hamas

A few days ago, Israeli armed personnel (dressed perfidiously as medical staff) [assassinated](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-68137050) three Palestinian militants being treated at a hospital in the West Bank. There are widespread reports, notably on X (formerly Twitter), indicating that one of the militants was in a coma. See, for instance, [this](https://voxpoliticalonline.com/2024/02/01/idf-hospital-raid-the-murdered-victims-were-either-in-a-coma-paraplegic-or-asleep/). However, I have not been able to verify this and am concerned that it might just be hearsay.

Is there any independent evidence substantiating that one of the militants was in a coma?

Comment: What is “perfidious” about minimising your risk and maximising your chances for success in a military action?

Comment: @gnasher729 It's the definition of perfidy. Yes, there's a military logic. But it's also a war crime, and ironically one the Zionist state has accused Hamas of.

Answer (score 11):

No. There isn't any reputable media resource that mentions a coma, I searched in Arabic too for pro-Palestinian resources and none of them mentioned having one of the assassinated in a coma.

However, media reported that one of them was paralyzed. From the BBC link:

> Dr Naji Nazzal said one of the men, who PIJ identified as its member, had been receiving treatment at the hospital since 25 October for a spinal injury which had left him paralysed.

[Al-Haq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Haq), an independent Palestinian human rights organization, [reported](https://www.alhaq.org/ar/advocacy/22567.html):

> وتواجد جميع الشهداء داخل المستشفى أثناء الهجوم، حيث أن باسل مصاب سابق بشظايا في الصدر والأطراف السفلية وأنحاء أخرى من جسمه، وكان قد أصيب بتاريخ 25 أكتوبر/تشرين الأول 2023، في قصف إسرائيلي أمام مقبرة شهداء مخيم جنين في حينه نتج عنه سقوط أربعة شهداء، وكان ما يزال منذ ذلك التاريخ يخضع للعلاج، ويعاني من حالة شبه شلل ويتلقى العلاج. أما محمد غزاوي فقد كان يرافق شقيقه باسل وكان برفقتهم أيضاً محمد جلامنة.

Translation (by myself):

> All the martyrs were present inside the hospital during the attack, Basil was previously injured in the chest, lower limbs, and other parts on October 25, 2023, in an Israeli bombing in front of the Jenin Camp Shudaa' cemetery at the time, which resulted in the death of four peope. Since that date, he has been undergoing treatment, suffering from semi-paralysis and receiving treatment. **As for Muhammad Ghazawi, he was accompanying his brother Basil, and Muhammad Jalamna was also accompanied by them**.

I conclude from that report that only one of them, Basel, was paralyzed and being treated.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: both are transliteration forms from the Arabic باسل and used interchangeably (for example see Wikipedia page for [Basil al-Khatib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basil_Al-Khatib), [Basil Hammad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basil_Hameed) and ['Bassel' al-Assad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bassel_al-Assad)). It's like Muhammed or Mohammed.

Comment: The words in the article seem to have been chosen to give a specific impression (e.g. that he was *paralysed at the time he was killed*), but there's nothing to show one way or the other whether he was completely cured of this by the time of the attack, and had remained in hospital while accompanying his brother, or because he was being treated for his other injuries.